# AppiumDriverLocalService auto download chrome

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, appium, appium-android

I have been trying to get started with appium by integrating it into a bdd framework so i can test a hybrid web app.
However I run into problems when switching the context to "WEBVIEW_chrome" because the correct chromedriver is not installed.

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/ states that i should run my local appium instance with the argument "chromedriver_autodownload" so it will always get the correct driver. However when i try to run the AppiumDriverLocalService as

```
AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder().usingAnyFreePort().withArgument(() -> "chromedriver_autodownload"));
service.start
```

the argument is refused.

All help to get this working is very much appreciated,
Other solutions or pointers to appium services that can help me download the correct chromedrivers automatically are also much appreciated.

I'm running appium 7.3.0 pulled from Maven Central

Answer (score 1):

A friend pointed out i was missing part of the argument.
correct usage:

```
AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder().usingAnyFreePort().withArgument(() -> "--allow-insecure","chromedriver_autodownload"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the specified default port to get this to work.

```
AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder().usingPort(4723).withArgument(() -> "--allow-insecure", "chromedriver_autodownload"));
```

Comment: How long does it take to download? I tried, and it timed out at 45 seconds.  Is it possible to pass appium --chromedriver-executable /Users/$User/Documents/chromeDrivers/103/chromedriver ? I have it on my local drive.

Answer (score 0):

For context switching in Selenium, I have to start as shown below.

appium --chromedriver-executable /Users/$User/Documents/chromeDrivers/103/chromedriver

Is it possible to run the above command by using 'AppiumDriverLocalService' class and 'AppiumServiceBuilder'
? Or Runtime class is the only option?